# Server class has databases, Database class need to know about Server

Tags: oop

I want to model a domain where there are many servers (e.g the production server, with `ProdServer` class associated). Each server inherit something from the `Server` class.  Each server has a list of databases associated (class `Database`), so the server always know of its databases. Each database should know something about server in which is hosted.

As far as I know, I would style the relationship between `Server` and `Database` as a composition association, since every server own the databases, and a database doesn't exist anymore without a related server (or maybe not?).

[image]

This is how I've styled this situation. Am I wrong? How can I improve this design?

- Is a mistake to consider a composition association as a biliateral one?
- In this way I hjve a loop of visibility. In `Database` class I can see the `Server` class, in the `Server` class I can see all databases hosted by that server and so on indefinitely (see image).

[image]

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it should belong to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Why would the Database class need to know anything about the server?

Comment: Cause each database has (behind the scene) a logfile associated(Database <>---->Logfile), and inside this log I need server info. Is this wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd make Server -> DB relation a one way link. Server knowns about DBs, but not the other way around. From your comment it sounds that Database has Logfile which in turn needs some information about Server, and that was the reason why reference to the server "leaked" into the DB. 
Extract that information that Logfile needs into a separate entity X and pass it on to DB at instantiation time. Note how you separated concerns - Server has X, DB has LogFile which knows X, but DB is ignorant about Server itself.

```
private interface Server{
    public String getFriendlyName();
    public String getMachineNameName();
    public Set<Database> getDatabases();
    public void createDatabase(String name);
}

private class ProdServer implements Server{
    private StuffThatLogfileNeeds stuffThatLogfileNeeds;
    private HashSet<Database> dbs = new HashSet<Database>();

    private ProdServer() {
        stuffThatLogfileNeeds = new StuffThatLogfileNeeds("bla bla");
    }

    @Override
    public String getFriendlyName() {
        throw new RuntimeException("Not implemented yet");
    }

    @Override
    public String getMachineNameName() {
        throw new RuntimeException("Not implemented yet");
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Database> getDatabases() {
        return new HashSet<Database>(dbs);
    }

    @Override
    public void createDatabase(String name) {
        Database database = new Database(name, stuffThatLogfileNeeds);
        dbs.add(database);
    }
}

private class Database{
    private String name;
    private StuffThatLogfileNeeds stuffThatLogfileNeeds;

    public Database(String name, StuffThatLogfileNeeds stuffThatLogfileNeeds) {
        this.name = name;
        this.stuffThatLogfileNeeds = stuffThatLogfileNeeds;
    }

    public String getName(){
        throw new RuntimeException("Not implemented yet");
    }
}

private class StuffThatLogfileNeeds{
    private String foo;

    private StuffThatLogfileNeeds(String foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }

    public String getFoo() {
        return foo;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you an example of what do you mesn for 'pass it on at instsnce time'?

Comment: Is StuffThatLogfileNeeds an association class between Server and DB composition? Something like: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/content/RationalEdge/sep04/bell/bell_fig11.jpg

Comment: No, it's just an entity that both Server and Database has. Black diamond, 1-to-1 on both sides